# Add location.pathname to React context

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing some theming for a gatsby project I'm working on. I have the `ThemeContext.Provider` and `ThemeContext.Consumer`. The layouts differ depending on what page you're on. I was wondering if it's possible to store `location.pathname` in the `ThemeProvider` and have the `path` returned in my `theme` object as the page route changes. I want to pass the path to specific components to adjust the layout depending on the route. Thank you.

ThemeProvider:

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react'

const defaultState = {
  dark: false,
  setDark: () => {},
}
export const ThemeContext = createContext(defaultState)

interface ThemeProviderProps {
  children: any
}

export const ThemeProvider = (props: ThemeProviderProps) => {
  const { children } = props.children
  const [dark, setDarkTheme] = useState<boolean>(false)

  const setDark = () => {
    setDarkTheme(true)
  }

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider
      value={{
        dark,
        setDark,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you're storing unnecessary data in a context which make the possibility of bad rendering performance higher.

All you need is to use `useLocation` hook if you use `Function Component` or `withRouter` HOC if you `Class Component` to access the `location` object in your Component. just remember to use `Router` provider and you good to go.